# php processing speed - unable to keep up with loop?

Tags: php

I have a simple loop that generates a random value and runs some basic checks. I find that the output is sometimes 'empty'.  In a run of 200 iterations, I might get 2 instances with 'empty' values.  Why is this?

```
<?php

$errors = [];

$total = 200;
for($c = 0; $c < $total; $c++) {

    $output = rand(0, 200);

    try {
        if(empty($output)) {
            throw new Error('No output provided');
        } elseif($output < 100) {
            throw new Error("$output is less than 100");
        } elseif(strlen($output) > 3) {
            throw new Error('Output more than 2 chars');
        }
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        array_push($errors, $errorMsg . '<br>');
    }
}

foreach($errors as $err) {
    echo $err;
}
```

UPDATE:
Comment #1 below is correct.  A zero number is seen as empty.

Comment: A zero number is seen as [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Silly me... should have checked the output.  You are 100% correct.  Should have realized this.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Why would the output from `rand` be _empty_ ?

Comment: When talking about performance don't use functions and variables where not necessary: `$errors[] = "{$e->getMessage()}<br>");`.